# Adding Log statements to method start and method end automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, nlog

I am currently given a task to add **log statements** to the project, for every **method** I need to add same **log statement** at the beginning of the **method** and at the end of the **method**. I am currently using **visual studio**. Is there any way or is there any option that I can use to add those **log statements** for all methods without the need of adding them manually.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an Aspect. In C# this can be achieved by using a Fody plugin: https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody. But be aware. Extensive logging will take down the performance of the application